# Scoring system collect item not updating Text UI - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created 2 scripts one which handles the collection of the item and another which handles the score being displayed to the screen. Currently the sound plays and the item is destroyed onTriggerEnter but the score's UI-Text does not update. I have tried to add the score inside ScoringSystem and CollectGem both scripts are below.

ScoringSystem is attached to a GameObject with TextScore assigned to the slot.

Can anybody see why the text would not be adding 1 on collection?

**CollectGem**

```
public class CollectGem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource collectNoise;

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        collectNoise.Play();
        ScoringSystem.theScore += 1;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

**Scoring System**

```
public class ScoringSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject score;
    public static int theScore;

    void update()
    {
        score.GetComponent<Text>().text = "Gems: " + theScore;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the [tag:unityscript] tag is for UnityScript, a JavaScript-like language that was deprecated in 2018.  If you're using C#, you aren't using UnityScript.  I've removed the tag.

Comment: Thank you for informing me on this

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the inspector with the ScoringSystem attached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Careful, spelling matters very much in our code.

`void update()` != `void Update()`

Seems like you just forgot to capitalize the name of ["Update"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html).

Comment: CELEBRATE DEREK, COME ON! Great spot Derek, thank you